# C# Casting to Generic type

Tags: c#, list, generics, casting

I've written these classes to make a composite, that can contain generic type and values.

And it seems ok, but I when I want to the composite, I run into a problem with converting the ISomething in the composite to Something and get its value.
I cannot cast the ISomethings in the list to their type, i.e. to something for instance.

Is there a trick to do here, or can't it be done?? (how should it be done??)
thanks
Kenneth

```
public interface ISomething
{
  string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Something<T> : ISomething
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public T Value { get; set; }

   public Something(string name, T value)
   {
      Name = name;
      Value = value;
   }
}

public class CompositeSomething : Something<IList<ISomething>>
{
   public CompositeSomething (string name)
      : base(name, new List<ISomething>())
   {
   }

   public void Add(ISomething newSomething)
   {
      Value.Add(newComponent);
   }

   public void Remove(ISomething oldSomething)
   {
      Value.Remove(oldSomething);
   }
}


XmlNode BuildXml(Something something, XmlDocument document)
{
    XmlNode node = document.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,
                   something.Name, "");
    foreach (ISomething item in compositeSomething.Value)
    {
        var isComposite = item is CompositeSomething;
        if (isComposite)
        {
            node.AppendChild(BuildXml((CompositeSomething)item, document));
        }
        else
        {
           var child = (Something<T>)item; // FAILS!!!!
           node.AppendChild(BuildXml(child,document));
        }
    }
    return node;
 }
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a list of `ISomething` at all - why not make `CompositeSomething` generic as well, with a list of `Something<T>`?

Comment: `var child = (Something<T>)item;` will not even compile regardless of your other code, because you've not placed it in a Generic method; `BuildXml` doesn't know what `T` is. You'll get better answers if you _clearly_ describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: good point, I added the <T> and it compiles, but to call it fails

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is simply given an `ISomething` how to access the value.

Try this:

```
Something<int> something1 = new Something<int>("Foo", 42);

ISomething something = (ISomething)something1;

Something<int> something2 = something as Something<int>;
if (something2 != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(something2.Value);
}
```

This gives me `42`.

The `as Something<int>` will only work produce a value if the original instance was a `Something<int>`, otherwise it will return `null`.

The other way to do it is to extend your interface and implementation like this:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    object Value { get; }  
}

public class Something<T> : ISomething
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    object ISomething.Value { get { return Value; } }

    public Something(string name, T value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
Something<int> something1 = new Something<int>("Foo", 42);

ISomething something = (ISomething)something1;

Console.WriteLine(something.Value);
```

Again this gives `42`.

You could further extend the code to give you the type of the value like this:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    object Value { get; }
    Type ValueType { get; }
}

public class Something<T> : ISomething
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    object ISomething.Value { get { return Value; } }
    Type ISomething.ValueType { get { return typeof(T); } }

    public Something(string name, T value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

You would still need to then use reflection to get the value anyway, but the interface gives it to you without the need for reflection.

---

Here's how to implement `BuildXml`.

Starting with the classes like this:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    object Value { get; }
    Type ValueType { get; }
}

public class Something<T> : ISomething
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    object ISomething.Value { get { return Value; } }
    Type ISomething.ValueType { get { return typeof(T); } }

    public Something(string name, T value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class CompositeSomething : Something<IList<ISomething>>
{
    public CompositeSomething (string name)
        : base(name, new List<ISomething>())
    {
    }

    public void Add(ISomething newSomething)
    {
        Value.Add(newSomething);
    }

    public void Remove(ISomething oldSomething)
    {
        Value.Remove(oldSomething);
    }
}
```

You can write `BuildXml` like this:

```
XElement BuildXml<T>(Something<T> something)
{
    var compositeSomething = something as CompositeSomething;
    if (compositeSomething != null)
    {
        MethodInfo z =
            this
                .GetType()
                .GetMethod("BuildXml", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance);
        return
            new XElement(
                compositeSomething.Name,
                compositeSomething.Value
                    .Select(x => z.MakeGenericMethod(x.ValueType).Invoke(this, new object[] { x }) as XElement));
    }
    else
    {
        return new XElement(something.Name, something.Value);
    }
}
```

I've opted to use LinqToXml to build the xml.

So, given this input:

```
var cs1 = new CompositeSomething("Foo");
cs1.Add(new Something<int>("Bar", 42));
cs1.Add(new Something<string>("Qaz", "Wix"));

var cs2 = new CompositeSomething("Rew");
cs2.Add(new Something<decimal>("Moo", 1.98m));
cs2.Add(cs1);
```

I can run `BuildXml(cs2)` to get this output:

```
<Rew>
  <Moo>1.98</Moo>
  <Foo>
    <Bar>42</Bar>
    <Qaz>Wix</Qaz>
  </Foo>
</Rew>
```

I think that's what you wanted.

Comment: yes but I would like to do it with the items in the list.
and I dont know the item type..

Comment: @kfn - I've added an easy way to get the value's type, but I suspect you want something more (which you can't get).

Comment: you suspection is right, I want to do more.. I want to use the typeinfo for info of what to cast to.., and i dont want it in the call to the build function..

Comment: @kfn - You can't use run-time type info to enable you to cast to anything. It just can't work. You have to invoke a method using reflection instead.

Comment: thanks - way back in C++ templates could be used..;-)

Comment: @kfn - I've added a `BuildXml` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Give your non-generic interface also a value property of type object and implement it explicitly:

```
public interface ISomething
{
  string Name { get; set; }
  object Value { get; }
}

public class Something<T> : ISomething
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public T Value { get; set; }

   public Something(string name, T value)
   {
      Name = name;
      Value = value;
   }

   public object ISomething.Value
   {
      get { return Value; }
   }
}
```

#### Update

There is no built-in mechanism to cast a non-generic object to a generic type object and directly access its values. In that case you could maybe use a dictionary as a type resolver (unproven, directly written here without compiler check):

```
private Dictionary<Type, Action<ISomething>> _TypeResolver = new Dictionary<Type, Action<ISomething>>();

private void InitializeTypeResolver()
{
    _TypeResolver.Add(typeof(Something<int>), ForInteger);
    _TypeResolver.Add(typeof(Something<double>), ForDouble);
}

private void ForInteger(ISomething source)
{
    // We know, we will only be called for this specific type, so a hard cast is the way to go.
    var something = (Something<int>)source;

    var value = something.Value; // Will be of type int.
    // ToDo: Whatever you want with that integer.
}

private void ForDouble(ISomething source)
{
     var something = (Something<double>)source;
     var value = something.Value; // Will be of type double.
}

private void Resolve(ISomething something)
{
     // ToDo: nullity checks.
     Action<ISomething> action;

     if(_TypeResolver.TryGetValue(something.GetType(), out action))
     {
         action(something);
     }
     else
     {
         // ToDo: What shall we do with the drunken sailor (or unknown type)?             
     }
}
```

Comment: but that would be just like making the list with objects.. and loosing the type info when I retrieve items in the list

Answer (score -1):

Implement a non-generic interface;

```
public interface IGetGenericTypeInstance
{
    object GenericTypeInstance();
}
```

Now I can cast the object to IGetGenericTypeInstance and GenericTypeInstance will return the property as type object.

Comment: So I should add the IGetGenerict... Interface to Something class, and go through object when getting from the list? ( and make the list only of objects?? )

Comment: Yes, add it to Something class